# scalaz-stream: combining queues based on one queue's size

Tags: scala, scalaz-stream

In my application I have up to N consumers working in parallel and a producer. Consumers grab resources from the producer, do their work, append results to an `updateQueue` and ask for more resources. Producer has some resources available initially and can generate more by applying updates from the `updateQueue`. It is important to apply all available updates before a new resource is emitted to a consumer. I've tried using a following generator, requesting updates "in bulk" whenever a consumer makes a request and setting aside new resources (which are not needed by the consumer but may be later requested by other consumers) in a `ticketQueue`:

```scala
      def updatesOrFresh: Process[Task, Seq[OptimizerResult] \/ Unit] =
        Process.await(updateQueue.size.continuous.take(1).runLast) {
          case Some(size) =>
            println(s"size: $size")
            if (size == 0)
              wye(updateQueue.dequeueAvailable, ticketQueue.dequeue)(wye.either)
            else
              updateQueue.dequeueAvailable.map(_.left[Unit])
        }.take(1) ++ Process.suspend(updatesOrFresh)
```

It doesn't work - initially available resource are emitted from the `ticketQueue.dequeue` and then it appears to block on the `wye`, logging:

```
size: 0
<<got ticket>>
size: 0
<<got ticket>>
size: 0   // it appears the updateQueue did not receive the consumer output yet, but I can live with that, it should grab an update from the wye anyway
<<blocks>>
```

when there were two resources available initially on the `ticketQueue`. However, if I change it to just

```
 val updatesOrFresh = wye(updateQueue.dequeueAvailable, ticketQueue.dequeue)(wye.either)
```

It works as expected (although without the "apply updates before emitting new resource" guarantee). How can I make it work ensuring the updates are applied at the right time?

---

Edit: I've solved it using the following code:

```
  val updatesOrFresh: Process[Task, Seq[OptimizerResult] \/ Unit] =
    Process.repeatEval {
      for {
        sizeOpt <- updateQueue.size.continuous.take(1).runLast
        nextOpt <-
          if (sizeOpt.getOrElse(???) == 0)
            wye(updateQueue.dequeueAvailable, ticketQueue.dequeue)(wye.either).take(1).runLast
          else
            updateQueue.dequeueAvailable.map(_.left[Unit]).take(1).runLast
      } yield nextOpt.getOrElse(???)
    }
```

However the question why the original `def` didn't work remains...